# android parse query only gets newest data on the column

Tags: java, android, parsing

```
   final String name =  getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
   ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Info");
   query.whereEqualTo("user", name);
   query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null){



                ArrayList<String> barbers = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (ParseObject object : objects){

                    barbers.add(String.valueOf(object.get("times")));

                }

                ArrayAdapter arrayAdaptar = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Barbers.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, barbers);

                list.setAdapter(arrayAdaptar);



            }
        }
    });
```

I am making a app where people put times and then other people can see all their times when they click their name. I have made this query to get all the times from that certain person that they clicked on but when the app runs it only gets me the newest time and if the person that you clicked is not the newest will not retrieve anything. Thank you, here are some screenshots of my Parse Server and of the query.

Comment: please post your adapter code

Comment: What is the adaptar code? sorry i am new to programming

Comment: You should not create an arrayadapter each time you call the findInBackground method. You must create the adapter inside the activity and update elements each time you call that method.

Comment: It still does the same thing and only gets the data from the newest name. for example if i am querying for the name Jonathan but there is another name after that one it will not get the data from jonathan even though it is still there